# Update multiple rows with set of values sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, sequential

I want to update multiple rows using update query. There is one primary key. I don't want to update the primary key. suppose

```
id name address age
 1  as  re3     20
 2  dg  ht5     21
 3  hf  ujy6    23
 4  ku  tr5     25
```

is the table.
I want to update the name, address and age sequentially.
I have a set of new values as input. like

("yJ","ht43",34)

("rt","fd43",36)

("hg","hgd4",40)

("ui","udg6",28)

How to update the rows sequentially with these values with update query?

Comment: how many rows you want to update???

Comment: as many rows i have as the input

Comment: And the table is a resultset . using TOP n . so i can retreive any number of row. if i have 5 set of inputs, i need to update the top 5 rows sequentially

Comment: you can use simply `update set name='...',age='...',address='...' where id=1`

Comment: can we update it as a set. giving inputs like .. update ("fsa","Sfsa",40)

Comment: no but like this `update set name='yJ',age='34',address='ht43' where id=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by assigning a Row number to both your existing values, and your new values. Then join the two data sets on this row number, and update accordingly:

```
WITH YourTableRanked AS
(   SELECT  t.*,
            RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID)
    FROM    YourTable AS t 
), NewValues  AS
(   SELECT  t.*,
            RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name)
    FROM    (VALUES
                ('yJ','ht43',34),
                ('rt','fd43',36),
                ('hg','hgd4',40),
                ('ui','udg6',28)
            ) AS t (Name, Address, Age)
)
UPDATE  T
SET     Name = v.Name,
        Address = v.Address,
        Age = v.Age
FROM    YourTableRanked AS t
        INNER JOIN NewValues AS v
            ON v.RowNum = t.RowNum;
```

It is worth noting that any kind of `TOP`, or ranking operation is either not valid syntax, or not particularly useful in the absence of an `ORDER BY` clause. So when you refer to updating rows "sequentially", in order for sequentially to have any meaning you need to define the order of this sequence. In the queries I have posted I have ordered by `Name` in your new values, and `ID` for your existing data, but you may wish to change this to suit your needs.

---

Full Example:

```
CREATE TABLE #T (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(2), Address VARCHAR(5), Age INT);
INSERT #T (id, name, address, age)
VALUES
    (1, 'as', 're3', 20),
    (2, 'dg', 'ht5', 21),
    (3, 'hf', 'ujy6', 23),
    (4, 'ku', 'tr5', 25);

WITH YourTableRanked AS
(   SELECT  t.*,
            RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID)
    FROM    #t AS t 
), NewValues  AS
(   SELECT  t.*,
            RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name)
    FROM    (VALUES
                ('yJ','ht43',34),
                ('rt','fd43',36),
                ('hg','hgd4',40),
                ('ui','udg6',28)
            ) AS t (Name, Address, Age)
)
UPDATE  T
SET     Name = v.Name,
        Address = v.Address,
        Age = v.Age
FROM    YourTableRanked AS t
        INNER JOIN NewValues AS v
            ON v.RowNum = t.RowNum;

SELECT  *
FROM    #T;

DROP TABLE #T;
```

Comment: @K9Code If this answers your question, please accept it (click on the checkmark), so that other people don't waste their time trying to resolve your (already solved) issue.